# conjugate partition definition

Tags: integer-partitions

i would like to understand basic  definition of  conjugate partition,this is what is said in my book

Let $υ = (u_1, u_2, . . . , u_n)$ be a sequence of integers such that $u_1 ≥ u_2 ≥ · · · ≥ u_n ≥ 0.$ The conjugate partition of $υ$ is $υ∗ = (u_1^*, u_2^*. . . , u_t^* )$, where $u_i^*$  is the number of js such that $u_j ≥ i$ . $t$ is sometimes taken to be $u_1$, but is
sometimes greater (obtained by extending with $0$s).

Examples:
$(4, 3, 2, 2, 1)^* = (5, 4, 2, 1).$

this is  what was said in my book,so as i understand from this conjugate partition does not mean complement of set(partition),but set with missed some element,for example in given example   we have missed ${3,2}$,so it means that we can create  a lot of  conjugate partition from given set  right?so it depend on person's aim  right?for exmaple we may get another partition by exclude  $5$  instead of $3$ right?please help me to clarify  everything

Comment: Have you looked at Ferrer diagrams?  I believe conjugate partitions refer to just taking the transpose.

Comment: The easiest way to conjugate:$ ROWS \rightarrow COLLUMNS$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
****
***
**
**
*
```

This is a way of representing the partition of a number $4+3+2+2+1 = 12$

If we flip this on its side, we get:

```
*****
****
**
*
```

This now represents the partition $5 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 12$.  Do you see how this works?

Comment: so it means that  result should be same?i mean it is something like transformation where for example length is  the same??

Comment: There is a unique conjugate partition for a given partition.  It is not a property of a bunch of partitions but rather a specific partition obtained by doing the above process.  Much like the conjugate of a complex number is a single complex number obtained by a certain process (negating the imaginary component)

Comment: nice then i understand it, iw as thinking that it would be  $5+2+2+1+1+1=12$ another one