# Proof of expected length in random division of $[0,1]$ interval

Tags: probability, combinatorics, proof-explanation, expected-value

I have trouble fully understanding the proof in a formal manner for the expected length of the $k^{th}$ smallest interval when we randomly divide the $[0,1]$ interval using $n$ points.

The $k^{th}$ smallest interval's expected length is equal to
$$\frac{\frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{k+1} + \dots + \frac{1}{n+1}}{n+1}$$
**Proof :** Without loss of generality, assume the $[0,1]$ segment is broken into segments of length $s_1 \geq s_2 \geq \dots \geq s_n \geq s_{n+1}$, in that order. We are given that $ s_1 + \dots + s_{n+1} = 1$, and want to find the expected value of each $s_k$.

Set $ s_i = x_i + \dots + x_{n+1} $ for each $ i = 1, \dots, n+1 $. Then, we have $ x_1 + 2x_2 + \dots + (n+1)x_{n+1} = 1 $, and want to find the expected value of $ s_k = x_k + \dots + x_{n+1} $.

If we set $y_i = ix_i $, then we have $ y_1 + \dots + y_{n+1} = 1 $, so by symmetry $ E[y_i] = \frac{1}{n+1} $ for all $ i $. Thus, $ E[x_i] = \frac{1}{i(n+1)} $ for each $ i $, and now by linearity of expectation
$
E[s_k] = E[x_k] + \dots + E[x_{n+1}] = \frac{1}{n+1} \left( \frac{1}{k} + \dots + \frac{1}{n+1} \right)
$

QED

I don't quite get how we use symmetry to claim that $E[y_i] = \frac{1}{n+1}$?

I would really appreciate help in filling out the gaps in my understanding.

Comment: You seem to have mistyped, $\Bbb E[x_i] = \frac{1}{i(n+1)}$

Comment: @DS Thanks for pointing that out. I fixed it.

Comment: What are $x_i$'s? How are they defined?

Comment: @sudeep5221 $x_i$'s are a way to redefine the lengths. We could view them as $s_{i}-s_{i+1} = x_{i}$ with $s_{n+1} = x_{n+1}$. It's easy to see this way all $x_i$'s are trivially $\geq 0$

Comment: Ah I see, thanks!

Comment: I believe the point is that while both the $s_i$ and $y_i$ have summation $=1$, the $s_i$ have the additional condition of being increasing, while the $y_i$ do not. However this alone does not answer why the $y_i$ defined in this particular fashion would have equal expectation.

Comment: I just noticed that the question finds the expected length of the kth **largest** interval, not smallest....

Comment: I see no much sense to speak about the expectations or the symmetry, when none of distributions of the points or the lengths is provided.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Why is that? If we randomly uniformly choose points in the $[0,1]$ interval, we can find the distributions corresponding to interval lengths (as shown in some other MathSE answers) and calculate the expectations based off that. I was amazed by this proof circumventing that and was wondering if it could be formalized.

Comment: In the question is not stated that the points dividing the interval are distributed uniformly.

Answer (score 6):

Let $\left(U_0, \ldots, U_{n}\right)$ the vector of random intervals. It is [known](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/430023/204532) that $$U_i \sim \frac{\epsilon_i}{\sum_{i=0}^{n}\epsilon_i}$$ where $\epsilon_i \sim \mathcal{E}(1)$ and independent. Using the order statistic,

$$S_i \sim \frac{\epsilon_{(n-i+1)}}{\sum_{i=0}^{n}\epsilon_{(i)}}$$

Since (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/80485/468504)) $$\epsilon_{(n-i+1)} \sim V_{n+1} + V_{n} + \ldots + V_{i} = \sum_{k=i}^{n+1} V_k$$ where $V_i \sim \mathcal E(i)$ and independent. You can write $V_i = \frac1i W_i$ where $W_i \sim \mathcal E(1)$ and independent. So $$\epsilon_{(n-i+1)} = \sum_{k=i}^{n+1} \frac1k W_k$$

Let $$X_i = S_{i} - S_{i+1} \sim \frac{\frac1i W_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\sum_{k=i}^{n+1} \frac1k W_k}$$ and $$Y_i = iX_i \sim \frac{W_i}{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} W_k}.$$

This proves the symmetry you are looking for.

Comment: A very rigorous proof

Comment: This is the only rigorous answer (so far), and the fact that it uses crucially properties of exponential random variables indicates that the "proof" in the question statement has a pretty big hole in it. Of course, it would be interesting if there were a more straightforward way to fix the op's "proof," but it's quite possible there is none.

Comment: @BobKrueger I guess the (so-called) proof in the OP provided by an author that had seen a proof like above before, and tried to simplify it.

Comment: @LM2357 Could you let us know where you have seen the OP's proof?

Answer (score 3):

This feels a bit like the conjugate partition picture (see for example [conjugate partition definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361560/conjugate-partition-definition)), and
it involves counting in the horizontal and vertical directions.

In your situation, you are doing nonnegative real numbers
$$
s_1\geq s_2\geq \dots\geq s_{n+1}\geq 0
$$
such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} s_i = 1$. You can represent these numbers as areas of stripes with width 1 and length $s_i$. Then the total area of the shape is 1.

Now compute the area column first. Then you partition the shape into $n+1$ rectangles, where the $i$-th one (from the **right**) would have width $i$ and length $x_i$, since $x_i=s_i-s_{i+1}$. Its area is
$$
ix_i=y_i,\quad\text{and }\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} y_i=1.
$$

Now it remains to say that to randomly partition an area of 1 into $n+1$ horizontal stripes is to randomly partition it into $n+1$ vertical rectangles.

So this helps explain what the $y_i$ are, and we have $E[y_i]=\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Here is a drawing of what I mean, which is drastically not up to scales: the $s_i$ are smaller than 1.
[image]

Comment: I don't get your construction. If your main square has length 1, how can you partition it into rectangles of width $i>1$? Maybe add a figure?

Comment: @DS I did add a drawing, and hope it helps.

Comment: I get it now, I have a similar approach that I will be sharing soon.

Answer (score 2):

Carrying the above idea's geometric intuition (for the case $n=3$):

[image: Figure1]

The different colours represent different $x_i$, and the $s_i$ are separated by darker lines. Call this figure 1.

Now, consider a rearrangement (figure 2):

[image: Figure2]

Note that the $ix_i$'s are separated by three (or $n$ for the general case) dark lines. Once you insert these 3 dark lines, you can easily insert the lighter lines (in exactly one way), i.e, the $ix_i$s are *uniquely* determined by the $n$ dark lines. Since these three lines can be randomly put anywhere inside the square, and are independent, the expected value of $ix_i$ is $1/4 = 1/(n+1)$.

---

More directly, there is a clear **bijection** between the representation of any configuration $(s_1;s_2;s_3;s_4)$ (or $(s_1;s_2;\ldots;s_{n+1})$ in the general case) between figure 1 and figure 2.

So instead of going from constructing figure 1, and converting to figure 2,  we do the reverse:

1. In a square, randomly draw $3$ (or $n$) vertical lines.
2. Call the $4$ regions so formed $y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4$ (or $y_1,y_2,\ldots y_{n+1}$).
3. Divide $y_i$ into $i$ equal parts, such that $x_i = y_i/i$ is the length of one part of $y_i$.
4. Now, there are $i$ copies of $x_i$. Rearrange them into groups such that $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4;x_2,x_3,x_4;x_3,x_4;x_4) := (s_1;s_2;s_3;s_4)$.

Note that the division of $y_i$ into subparts of length $x_i$ in Step $3$ takes place **after** Step 1. So, step 3 **does not** affect the expected value of $y_i$ in step 1. By a reasonable assumption of an uniform distribution and using **symmetry**, $\Bbb E[y_i] = 1/4$ (or $1/(n+1)$ in the general case).

---

(Images are not to scale, I hope the colours depict my idea. Also, I think $\Bbb E[s_k]$ is the expected value of the $k$th **largest** segment, not the $k$th smallest.)

Comment: I think the edited addendum directly answers the OPs question in the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Here I will try and expand a justification for the symmetry of the $y$ variables:

$y_1,y_2,\dots y_{n+1}$ can be considered as independent variables, except for the fact that they sum up to $1$. Unlike the $s$ variables, there is no ordering relation between them.

Apart from that, they can be given any set of $n+1$ values in the $[0,1]$ interval. And any such assignment corresponds uniquely and linearly to a valid assignment of the $s_1,s_2,\dots s_{n+1}$ variables. The linearity of the transformation between $s$ and $y$ shows "probability volume" is preserved in the change of variable. Given this correspondence, and uniform distribution of the initial variables, we can assume the assigned values of $y$ can be permuted, leading to equiprobable events in the $s$ variables. Therefore $\forall r\neq p, E(y_r) = E(y_p)$. Due to their sum being $1$, we get $E(y_r) = \frac{1}{n+1}$.

---

To get more intuition on this, I will work out an example for $n= 1$,

Consider an event which gives the values $(v_1,v_2)$ to our variables $(s_1,s_2)$. 
We get values
$(v_1-v_2,v_2)$ for the variables $(x_1,x_2)$ and 
$(v_1-v_2,2 v_2)$ for $(y_1,y_2)$.

Given that initial distributions were uniform, the transformations linear, and the $y$s have no constraints apart from being in the interval $[0,1]$ and summing to $1$, we can say the for the variables  $(y_1,y_2)$ the values $(v_1-v_2,2v_2)$ are as probable as the values $(2v_2,v_1-v_2)$ (permutation is a volume-preserving transformation). This means (working backwards) that we can equiprobably assign values 
$(2v_2,(v_1-v_2)/2)$ to $(x_1,x_2)$ and 
$(2v_2 + (v_1-v_2)/2,(v_1-v_2)/2)$ to $(s_1,s_2)$. 
Knowing that $v_1 + v_2$ is constrained to be $1$ we can rewrite that as $(\frac{3}{2}-v_{1},\frac{1}{2}-v_{2})$. Ie. for $(s_1,s_2)$, the event $(v_1,v_2)$ is as equiprobable as the event $(\frac{3}{2}-v_1,\frac{1}{2}-v_{2})$. Knowing these events as equiprobable we can compute the expected value of a variable as the average its assigned value in equiprobable events.  Ie. $E(s_1) = (E(v_1) + E(\frac{3}{2}-v_1))/2 =\frac{3}{4}$ . For $y_1$ we get $((v_1-v_2) + 2v_2)/2 = 1/2$.

The same trick can be applied to $n=2$ or higher:
Assign an event to $(s_1,s_2,s_3)$, compute the corresponding values to $(y_1,y_2,y_3)$, cycle their values, then work backwards to get  equiprobable events for $(s_1,s_2,s_3)$ (for $n=2$, we need $2$ more events, corresponding to the cycles values of $(y_1,y_2,y_3)$). Then we may compute the expected values as the average of such grouped equiprobable events.